# TortoiseSVN not allowing me to commit files that I've edited

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was able to import my project to my repository folder and I can look at a working copy, but when I want to Commit the project the dialog box that pops up says that no changes have been made. Also, there is no green check mark next to my working project folder.

The steps I went through:

1. Create repository folder,
2. created repository there,
3. created working copy folder,
4. imported my project folder into the working copy folder.

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Sounds like you missed the "check out repository" step.

Comment: I did that and still nothing

Comment: Have you explicitly add (context menu -> add) your new content?

Comment: In step 4 instead of "import" it has to be "SVN Checkout". Then 5. add files to WC, and 6. SVN Commit.

Comment: @Dialecticus - after import files are already in repository, adding not needed

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the subject more specific. "TortoiseSVN problems" is meaningless; we can see in the tags that it's a TortoiseSVN question, which leaves your title as "problems", and that is worthless as far as information. Your subject should describe something **specific** about the problem you're having, and should be something that provides information when it turns up in a search result for future users of this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you import anything in Subversion, you import **unversioned files** directly **into repository**. They will not appear in WC until you checkout repository into WC

PS: you can decrease amount of entities, if after import `svn co -f` (`--force` because target folder isn't empty) into project folder (you'll get the same files, but versioned and inside Working Copy)

Comment: I just did a checkout from my repository into my working copy folder and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given very much information. How did you create your repository? What are all of your steps? What are you using for your server?

---

First thing first. What is the status of all the files you put into your working directory? Did you tell Subversion you want to *add them*? When you do a commit, you should see on the bottom of the place where you enter your commit comment what files are being committed. Is that empty? If so add them.

---

I'm going to make some wild assumptions because this is something I've seen when people are playing around with Subversion: The issue is that `svnserve` (if that's what you're using as a repository server daemon) is configured by default to allow for anonymous checkouts, but not anonymous commits.

Many users attempt to create the repo:

```
$ svnadmin create repo
```

Then start up `svnserve`:

```
$ svnserve -r repo
```

Then successfully checkout a working copy. Looks like everything works! Then, the make changes, and try a commit. Not allowed.

Go to the directory that contains your Subversion repository. Under that is a directory called `conf`. Under that are two files: `svnserve.conf` and `passwd`.

Edit `svnserve.conf`. You can do one of two things: Look for the line that says `# anon-access = read`. This is the default: Anonymous access allows you to do a checkout. Remove that `#` and change `read` to `write`. That line should look like this:

```
anon-access = write
```

Now, anonymous access is allowed to do commits. Try committing your change.

Or, you can look a wee bit further down for `password-db`. This is the file to use as the password database. By default, it's not used. Remove that `#`:

```
password-db = passwd
```

Now, edit that `passwd` file and put in a user ID and password. Use that when you commit your changes with the `--username` parameter.

I hope this solves your issue. If you can give me a bit ore information, I can give a better answer.